# How to put (dot) to between of the number

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the type of the number but I don't know how and what keyword to search:

I would like to change the basic type of number in html from:

```
2000000 -> 2.000.000
```

And it will show on the screen the number have the dot in between.[image]

ps: the input is number, do I need to use Javascript to convert it to string and add to html?

Comment: `do I need to use Javascript to convert it to string and add to html?`, probably yes.

Comment: Is this number the result of a form or script process where one number would be `3.200.000` and another number might be `55.000`?

Comment: What kind of syntax for quickly transform this number to the number with the dot in between?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use JavaScript to do it.

```
const separateNumber = (n) => {
  return String(n).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1.")
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate! That what I am looking for